# How to Merge Two APKs into one APK - Android

Tags: android, apk

I have following scenario:

I have two apks and I want to create a single apk from both apks. I don´t have the source code for one of them. So my question is:

Is it possible to merge both apks into a single apk?

Comment: It is kinda possible, try anti split app...

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. An apk is a special format, you can't just put A and B together. Especially if you dont have the source.

Comment: I agree that it is not possible. What would it exactly merge? Split screen for both apps? :/